# How to close component is JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this example of tabs implementation:

```
public class JavaFX_uiTabPane extends Application {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      primaryStage.setTitle("http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/");
      Group root = new Group();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, Color.WHITE);

      TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
      BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

      //Create Tabs
      Tab tabA = new Tab();
      tabA.setText("Tab A");
      tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);

      Tab tabB = new Tab();
      tabB.setText("Tab B");
      tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);

      Tab tabC = new Tab();
      tabC.setText("Tab C");
      tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);

      mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);

      mainPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
      mainPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

      root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

I'm interested how I can make the component closeable. I want to put a small button at the right corner which when it's pressed the component is removed from the main stage. Is this possible with JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own tabs by extends `Tab` and try to customize it to include the small button you want. And after you will can add it to your `TabPane`